# Why the argument is final in the single handler catch statement

Tags: java, exception

In case of single handler `catch` statement to handle more than one exceptions, why the argument is implicitly `final`?

```
catch (IOException|SQLException ex) {
    logger.log(ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

In this code ex is `final`. Why is it so?

Answer (score 3):

Otherwise you might get tempted to write something like `ex = new IOException();`, but since the type is not actually `IOException` or `SQLException`, it would break type safety in a weird way.

Comment: This could be phrased a little more strongly. `IOException | SQLException` is formally a *union* type. You can assign to it from the union of `IOException` and `SQLException` instances, but you can perform the intersection of their operations. Technically it could be allowed to reassign `ex` according to the rules for union types, but it would open the doors for confusing code, various types of abuse, and probably some ugly and counterintuitive edge cases. Since this fetaure was meant to have a very clear and narrow scope of utility, it was a reasonable choice to prevent reassignment.

Comment: If, in case, both IOException and SQLException is raised in try block, how could the argument be used for both the exception if it is final?